# Display images from private local Storage in Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I am playing around with Laravel and want to build a private website. So I want to store my images in the storage/app/images folder. I want to do that for a list of countries. For the test, I did not store the file name in the database, but renamed the images to follow a property named code.

I read a lot of topics here in stackoverflow or in other places where people ask for the same thing, but I do not manage to make it work.

Here is what I have.

I first wrote a route:

```
Route::get('medias/images/{folder}/{image}',[
    'uses' => 'MediaController@imageShow',
    'middleware' => 'auth'
]);
```

I then created the associated controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

class MediaController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @param $folder
     * @param $image
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function imageShow($folder, $image)
    {
        $file = Storage::url('images/'.$folder.'/'.$image);

        return response()->file($file);
    }
}
```

And in my view, I have:

```
<img src="{{ action('MediaController@imageShow', ['folder' => 'countries', 'image' => $country->code.'.png']) }}" />
```

This does not work at all. I don't have the file displayed. I then want to go further with having a default image when the image does not exist, but first I need to solve this situation.
I have absolutely no idea how to debug this, I got no error displayed.

Thanks for your help

Comment: is `storage/app/` symlinked to somewhere in `public` ? If not you will have to use php to return a file response of some type as the webserver can't serve files that aren't in `public`.

Comment: Hi, isn't it what I did with `return response()->file($file);`? return a file response of some type?

Comment: Yes, but in your code you are trying to get a url instead of a file path to the file.

Comment: I changed url with get but it does not change anything.

Comment: again, you pass a 'file path' to `file`, and you may or may not have to adjust the disposition.

Comment: So basically, there is no other way of doing it but using storage_path() instead of Storage::?